# Why is either PHPMailer or SendMail not working?

Tags: php, smtp, webserver, phpmailer, sendmail

I have a php script that uses phpmailer:

```
require("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->IsSendmail();
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->SetFrom($from, 'BuzzZap');

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress($to, $to);
if ($mail->Send()) {
    echo "Message sent!";
    return true;
} else {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    return false;
}
```

(Some variables are defined elsewhere, but are definitely defined)
So, I have sendmail running on port 25 and 587 (says when I run `netstat -tulnp`) on a live server. The script does say "successfully sent" and produces no errors, warnings, etc. Mail.log shows:

```
 8 17:33:23 casparwylie sendmail[2601]: u18HXNFd002601: Authentication-Warning: casparwylie: www-data set sender to billing@buzzzap.com using -f
Feb  8 17:33:23 casparwylie sendmail[2601]: u18HXNFd002601: from=billing@buzzzap.com, size=2178, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<5e0e6f2a4e12ddb8524541a13b2a76a1@buzzzap.com>, relay=www-data@l$
Feb  8 17:33:23 casparwylie sm-mta[2602]: u18HXNK9002602: from=<billing@buzzzap.com>, size=2393, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<5e0e6f2a4e12ddb8524541a13b2a76a1@buzzzap.com>, proto=ESMTP, dae$
Feb  8 17:33:23 casparwylie sendmail[2601]: u18HXNFd002601: to="casparwylie@googlemail.com" <casparwylie@googlemail.com>, ctladdr=billing@buzzzap.com (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:0$
Feb  8 17:33:23 casparwylie sm-mta[2604]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Feb  8 17:33:24 casparwylie sm-mta[2604]: u18HXNK9002602: to=<casparwylie@googlemail.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=122393, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [7$
Feb  8 17:33:26 casparwylie sendmail[2606]: u18HXQoo002606: Authentication-Warning: casparwylie: www-data set sender to billing@buzzzap.com using -f
Feb  8 17:33:26 casparwylie sendmail[2606]: u18HXQoo002606: from=billing@buzzzap.com, size=2178, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<2a08b37d9e3ea189c1e61648a3e2e5f8@buzzzap.com>, relay=www-data@l$
Feb  8 17:33:26 casparwylie sm-mta[2607]: u18HXQXe002607: from=<billing@buzzzap.com>, size=2393, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<2a08b37d9e3ea189c1e61648a3e2e5f8@buzzzap.com>, proto=ESMTP, dae$
Feb  8 17:33:26 casparwylie sendmail[2606]: u18HXQoo002606: to="casparwylie@googlemail.com" <casparwylie@googlemail.com>, ctladdr=billing@buzzzap.com (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:0$
Feb  8 17:33:26 casparwylie sm-mta[2609]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Feb  8 17:33:26 casparwylie sm-mta[2609]: u18HXQXe002607: to=<casparwylie@googlemail.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=122393, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [7$
```

for each email I try to send.

However, I quite simply do not receive an email when checking casparwylie@gmail.com.

Would appreciate any help - I'm clearly misunderstanding something!

Comment: Did you already tried putting $mail->Send(); before the if clause?

Comment: `verify=FAIL` doesn't look good.

Comment: @Rhopercy, will try now. Synchro, agreed. No idea exactly what it is on about though.

Comment: SMTP to port 587 on localhost will still require both TLS encryption and authentication. You don't need them if you call `isMail()` instead of `isSMTP()` or `isSendmail()`. BTW what Rhopercy said makes no sense.

Comment: Yes - i didn't think it did. I will try isMail() now and report back, thanks @Synchro

Comment: Still hasn't worked - could it be something to do with my sendmail configuration?

Answer (score 1):

While You are sending e-mails thru `SMTP` located at localhost You don't have to specify `SMTP` related settings. So try to remove these lines:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->IsSendmail();
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Port = 587;
```

**Note: don't forget to check Your `SPAM` folder**

Comment: This isn't really an answer. It's good practice to use SMTP to localhost, not least because it gives better traceability, debug output and performance.

Comment: @Synchro, PHPMailer by default  is using `SMTP` on localhost, thus there is no need to specify any additional settings.

Comment: No; It uses `mail()` by default, which uses whatever sendmail binary you have configured in php.ini, and has nothing to do with PHPMailer's SMTP support.

Comment: @CasparWylie, try to enable debugging with: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;`

Comment: Will do - sounds hopeful!

Comment: @CasparWylie, have You checked ur `spam` folder?

Comment: Amazing. all this time and i have 200 emails from my server...in spam. Thank you very much ! One question, it has sent as from an old hostname, where can i change mail() default hostname? ( want to change xx:   hello@xx.com)

Comment: @CasparWylie, depending on distribution you use look for /etc/hostname or /etc/sysconfig/network. Change hostname there and restart `sendmail`
Another option is to set `From` & `Reply` address with `PHPMailer`:
$mail->Sender = '';
$mail->From = '';
$mail->FromName = '';
$mail->addReplyTo('');
but in this case ur old hostname will be visible in the header of ur e-mail.

Comment: I have changed the /etc/hostname and /etc/sysconfig does not exist - I will try adding the reply property too. Will be a sec.

Comment: have done all you have mentioned but still receiving emails from old hostname. really weird behaviour. Any other ideas?

Comment: @CasparWylie or just execute `$ hostname new_hostname` and then execute `service network restart` & `service sendmail restart`.
Then You can check ur new `hostname` by simply typing: `$ hostname`